# runtime exception during nutch generate

Tags: nutch, runtimeexception, gora

I'm trying to run nutch for the first time and while executing

/bin/nutch generate -topN 5

I get the following exception:

```
GeneratorJob: starting at 2016-02-13 21:01:42
GeneratorJob: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
GeneratorJob: starting
GeneratorJob: filtering: true
GeneratorJob: normalizing: true
GeneratorJob: topN: 5
GeneratorJob: java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=apache-nutch-    2.3.1.jar, jobid=job_local1061440919_0001
at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:120)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.run(GeneratorJob.java:227)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.generate(GeneratorJob.java:256)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.run(GeneratorJob.java:322)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.main(GeneratorJob.java:330)
```

Here is the stacktrace from hadoop.log:

```
2016-02-13 21:01:44,541 ERROR mapreduce.GoraRecordReader - Error reading Gora records: null
2016-02-13 21:01:44,557 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local1061440919_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException:   java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at org.apache.gora.mapreduce.GoraRecordReader.nextKeyValue(GoraRecordReader.java:122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.firstKey(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:2036)
    at org.apache.gora.memory.store.MemStore.execute(MemStore.java:128)
    at org.apache.gora.query.impl.QueryBase.execute(QueryBase.java:73)
    at org.apache.gora.mapreduce.GoraRecordReader.executeQuery(GoraRecordReader.java:67)
    at org.apache.gora.mapreduce.GoraRecordReader.nextKeyValue(GoraRecordReader.java:109)
    ... 12 more
```

I've been following the tutorial here: https://github.com/renepickhardt/metalcon/wiki/simpleNutchSolrSetup for setting up nutch.

I've seen a few posts on stackoverflow and the nutch archives with similar exceptions, and they've suggested that I might be running out of disk space in my /tmp directory but the /tmp directory only has about 8MB worth of data on it.
Other than this, I'm clueless about what is causing this exception

What could be the cause of this exception?

I'm using Nutch 2.3.1 along with HBase 1.1.3 as the datastore and I'm running it on Ubuntu 15.10

Thanks

Comment: Looking the hadoop's log, I think you are using MemStore, and not HbaseStore. Did you configure `gora.properties`?

Comment: That fixes things. Thank you!

Comment: I will post the answer, I have 3 points left to 1K ;) You are welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking the hadoop's log, I think you are using MemStore, and not HBaseStore. Did you configure gora.properties?

Copied from my comment :)

Comment: Further information about why MemStore does not work with Nutch 2.3.1: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39834423/582789